# How to activate ASP.NET fileupload from code behind?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, code-behind

i'm developing an application and i need to activate fileupload from code behind, 
anyone knows how to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: You mean open the box for the user to select the file, or begin the upload (== submit the form), or something else?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You can't initiate a post from the server - it has to be done from the client.

Comment: Yes Rup what i ment was to open the box for the user to select the file

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like that. This has to be triggered on client side.

```
<html>
<head>
<script lang="text/javascript">
function openDialog(){
    document.getElementById('fileupload').click();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload='openDialog()'>

<input type="file" id="fileupload" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you need. please use FileUpload control in ASP.NET 2.0 on wards.

Comment: Great. please use this control directly.

Comment: I can't, it's hidden and i need to activate it from a button